# Service postgresql is stopped in the running docker container with postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have running container `docker run -it --rm -d postgres`. I can even connect to it with 172.17.0...:5432 IP. But

```
$service --status-all
 [ - ]  cron
 [ - ]  exim4
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  postgresql
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  sysstat
```

How can postgres work if service even hasn't been started ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any port mappings when starting the container. My guess is that you are connecting to your locally installed Postgres instance instead of your postgres container.

Start the postgres container with: `docker run --rm -p:5433:5432 -d postgres`

Then connect by using the port 5433.

Comment: `psql -h 172.17.0.3 -p 5432 -U postgres` it's my request to docker bd (I do not connect with local bd) . Mapping didn't help and I see no connection between mapping and running the service postgresql.